# Utterly confused about loading SQLite data in Honeycomb (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am new to android development and I've hit a hurdle when trying to load SQLite data to populate a ListFragment. In previous versions of android one made a new instance of the cursor class, made an SQLite query to place the cursor in the appropriate position, called startManagingCursor, made a new SimpleCursorAdapter and finally called setListAdapter. Pretty darn simple (too bad about the UI thread)!

Now almost all of these methods are deprecated and I have no idea how to populate my poor ListView. The documentation says I should use CursorLoader but here on StackOverflow people advise against using it for SQLite queries. How do I tell my cursor to populate the ListView?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert you DbAdapter into a Content Provider if you want to use CursorLoaders. and put a`ndroid:exported= false` as a property of your content provider so that it is private. Android team is favoring this approach as they say Content Provider is better suited to handle logic. That is why they are bent on deprecating our old ways( was hard on me too). But I have changed my dbadapters to content providers and now gleefully using cursor loaders( they are too cool not to be used). Try it, generally you will do fine with some more boilerplate code of Content Providers in adition to that of DBadapter and sqliteHelper. GO for it!

Comment: New to Android/SQLite, I would love nothing more than an example... ;-)

Comment: search google for code to Content Providers, and you will find plenty... I have answered the question . Please upvote and approve this answer